# How do you break down your android GUI for documentation?

Tags: android, user-interface

I've hired a graphic designer to improve the UI for an app I'm working on, but he's not familiar with the way android UI's are layed out.  I'm wondering what others use for trying to document the way a UI comes together  (see example below) from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

[image]

Are there any tools that can do something like this, or do I need to just take screenshots then draw boxes and stuff around the various xml/drawable resource and annotate them?